# Laravel Relationship: a table having ids from two other tables

Tags: laravel, relationship

I have two tables: 'tours' and 'tourists' in my DB.

A 'tour' can have MANY 'tourist's, and 'tourist' can participate in MANY 'tour's.
So, I have successfully related them via 'begonsToMany" relationship (when adding rows to "tours' and 'tourists" an intermediate table 'tour_tourist' is given a row also.

"tour_tourist" table structure is:

```
tour_id | tourist_id
      1 | 37
      1 | 38
      1 | 39
```

*(tourists with id's 37, 38 and 39 go are assinged to the tour with id = 1)*

THE PROBLEM : One of 'tourists' (37 or 38 or 39 from example abouve) can be a 'buyer' of the 'tour' (1 from above table). So only 1 person pays for the tour. Also this person can go to the tour/only pay for it. I pass this data (tour, tourists, who is buyer and does he goes to the tour) when submitting a tour via web-form.

So I want to create a 3rd table, called 'buyers' which represent a "tourist" who pays for the tour:

```
tour_id | tourist_id | is_tourist
   1    |     39     |     0
```

*(1. one 'tour_id' can match only ONE 'tourist_id')*

*(2. 'tourist_id' should be one of those who 'belong' to the 'tour_id' in the previous "tour_tourist" table - tourist 39 belongs to tour 1 - see table above).*

*(3. 'is_tourist' is 1/0, means the buyer goes to the tour/only pays, in my example it's 0 - he only pays, doesn't go).*

I am wondering how can I do this using Eloquent relationships (one-to-one? hasManyThrough?) .

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you really need that 3rd table? Shouldn't you just add a column "buyer_id" to the tour table (since there can be only one buyer) ?

Comment: if there was no "is_tourist" I would do so. But since I have one extra-argument, it seems to me that it's better to have a separate table for the buyers....

Comment: But the "is_tourist" is already implicit if the tourist is in the tour_tourist table and he is related to that tour. You will have duplicated information for being a tourist. In the "buyers" table and in the "tour_tourist" table

Comment: what do you mean by 'implicit', Amarnasan?:) Anyway, I just really want to know how-to-do-it!:)

Comment: By "implicit" I mean that you already have the information of the buyer being or not a traveler because you already have that information in the tour_tourist page. Sorry being so picky, but I only want to make your code (and life) less complicated that it needs to be :)

Comment: I see your point, Amarnasan! Maybe i'll do it this way, if no one gives me the answer:)

Answer (score 0):

Probably a simpler approach for that is to create two other columns called `is_payer` and `is_tourist` in your `tour_tourist` table in order to avoid creating your third table.

The result of your `tour_tourist` table could be something like this:

```
tour_id | tourist_id | is_payer | is_tourist
   1    |     37     |     1    |     0/1
   1    |     38     |     0    |      1
   1    |     39     |     0    |      1
```

Then with eloquent you can simply access your extra columns' using `withPivot`  method chaining your `belongsToMany` method.

For example, your Tour model can be something like this:

**Tour**

```
class Tour extends Eloquent {
  protected $table = 'tours';

  public function tourists() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Tourist')->withPivot('is_payer', 'is_tourist');
  }
}
```

In the result you will have `is_payer` & `is_tourist`.

You can then filter them out using Collection methods.

Comment: thank you, Ahmad! I've already thought about it and it's a good solution to the problem. It's not perfect though, because we have a lot of extra 0 and 1s in 'is_payer' and 'is_tourist'. And creating a third table is just kind of challenge for me, I think that I'll be a much better laravel developer if I can handle problems like this.

Comment: You can always use a third table if you'd like to. in order to access your third table you can either use a nested Eager Loading.

For example like this:
`Tour::with(['tourists' => function($q) { $q->with('payers') }])`